# Removing a file from an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a way for users to view and/or delete their images before they upload them. I have gotten relatively far; however, I'm stuck on one piece.

```js
let images = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
      var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        var f = files[i]
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
          $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\"  />" +
            "<br/><span class=\"remove\"><button>remove</button></span>" +
            "</span>").appendTo("#img-upload");
          $(".remove").click(function() {
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
            //Delete image from images array here
          });
        });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API")
  }
});

function addImagesToList() {
  let newImages = document.getElementById("files").files;
  for (var i = 0; i < newImages.length; i++) {
    images.push(newImages[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple accept='image/*' required="required" onchange="addImagesToList();" />
  <div id="img-upload"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/qa8hmub4/

I haven't been able to figure out how to actually remove the file from the array. I can get it to disappear from the screen but it remains in the array. Please help!

Comment: You probably want to add the event listeners after they have been appended to img-upload, via a trigger on that. If you upload multiple items at the same time, your buttons are incorrectly added

Comment: If you're asking how to get an entry out of the `FileList` object associated with the `<input type=file>` element involved, the answer is that you cannot do that.

Comment: @Pointy Do you have any suggestions on how to rework this so that I could solve this issue?

Comment: @Ballard The buttons are correctly added in my code, I'm not sure how I messed up the snippet.

Comment: The browser API simply will not allow you to modify the `FileList`.  Only the person using the browser can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.index()` method to get the index in the `images` array, and then with `splice` you can perform the deletion.

Change:

```
$(this).parent(".pip").remove();
```

To:

```
var $el = $(this).parent(".pip");
images.splice($el.index(), 1);
$el.remove();
```

There is however an issue in your code: you are creating the click handler for all `.remove` buttons over and over again in a loop. You should remove the click handler *outside* the loop, outside the `onload` handler, and outside of the change handler of the file input. You should only define the button click handler once, using event delegation, so it will work for *future* remove buttons.

Here is a reduced demo, removing the file upload part, and focussing just on the HTML list and the `images` array:

Demo:

```js
var images = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
for (var f of images) {
  $("<span class=\"pip\">" + f +
            "<span class=\"remove\"><button>remove</button></span>" +
            "<br></span>").appendTo("#img-upload");
}

// Define this outside the "change" handler for your file input
// This `on` call should only execute once:
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $el = $(this).parent(".pip");
  images.splice($el.index(), 1);
  $el.remove();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(images)); // for demo: display current array
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-upload">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work; the images.splice doesn't return an array of images.

Comment: The return value of `splice` is not important here. This call takes out one item at the given index.

Comment: See the snippet I have added, which demonstrates that `splice` works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're absolutely right. It was just causing a different problem. Do you have any idea why mine would be removing all the images when I click the delete button? After console logging it, it seems like it loops through and deletes each element. I know it'd be because of the loop (duh), but I don't know another way to do the file reader for each file.

Comment: That is because your click handler is added multiple times on the same buttons. As I wrote in my answer, you need to define the click handler *outside* of the loop. And if the `change` event occurs multiple times on the file input, then it should even be defined outside that handler, using an `on("click"` syntax instead of `.click()`.

Comment: Doesn't the click handler need to be attached to the fileReader?

Comment: There are three levels of handlers at stake: the  change handler, the onload handler and the button click handler. The latter should be defined outside of the two other handlers. Otherwise you will duplicate button click handlers. See update of my answer. Not sure why someone downvoted it, as it is clear from the snippet that this solution works.

Comment: This is all and great, but it is not going to remove the files from the file input. Code will have to do something different to upload the files than use the input element with a form submission.

Comment: @epascarello, you seem to read the question differently from me: I read that the question is about removing from the array `images`.

Comment: *"... users to view and/or delete their images before they upload them."*

Comment: Yes, but that is the introduction of the background, not the question. OP continues: *"I'm stuck on one piece."* and that piece is about the array. This is an answer to *that* piece.

Comment: YES, it works. thanks so much for explaining and the helpful code